# Concatenate SMS via SMPP

Tags: java, sms, smpp

I'm having an issue where I can't send SMS more than 255 words. I did my research a bit on how to concatenate the messages but I still can't get it to work. Can somebody advise me on this? Below is my code:

```
private int SMSMt(String pstrLoginName, String pstrServiceID, String 
pstrCPID, String pstrMSISDN, String pstrKeyword, String pstrPriceCode, 
String pstrChargeMSISDN, String pstrSubID, String pstrDstTrxID, String 
pstrShortCode, String pstrSMS, String pstrLanguage, SubmitResult pobjRst)
{
    int intResult = 0;
    try
    {
        if (!this.mobjSMPP.mblnBound)
        {
            intResult = 9910;
        }
        else
        {
            SubmitSM objReq = new SubmitSM();
            Address objSrcAddress = new Address();
            Address objDstAddress = new Address();

            objSrcAddress.setNpi((byte)1);
            objSrcAddress.setTon((byte)0);
            objSrcAddress.setAddress(pstrShortCode);

            objDstAddress.setNpi((byte)1);
            objDstAddress.setTon((byte)0);
            objDstAddress.setAddress(pstrMSISDN);

            objReq.setServiceType("");
            objReq.setSourceAddr(objSrcAddress);
            objReq.setDestAddr(objDstAddress);
            objReq.setReplaceIfPresentFlag((byte)0);

            objReq.setScheduleDeliveryTime("");
            objReq.setValidityPeriod("");
            objReq.setPriorityFlag((byte)1);
            objReq.setRegisteredDelivery((byte)1);
            objReq.setUserMessageReference((short)25);

            WriteLog("pstrLanguage=" + pstrLanguage);
            if (pstrLanguage.equals("1")) {
                objReq.setDataCoding((byte)8);
                WriteLog("Ori pstrSMS=" + pstrSMS);
                objReq.setShortMessage(pstrSMS,"UTF_16BE");

                //String HexStr = new String("A" + "\u00ea" + "\u00f1" + "\u00fc" + "\u0eaa" + "C");
                //WriteLog("HexStr=" + HexStr);
                //pstrSMS = stringToHex(pstrSMS);

                //StringConverter TestRun = new StringConverter(pstrSMS);

                /*pstrSMS = HexStr;*/
                //pstrSMS = new String("\u0eaa");
                //pstrSMS = new String("0x0eaa");

                /*pstrSMS = "世界您好";
                WriteLog("Ori pstrSMS=" + pstrSMS);
                //byte[] messageData = new ASCIIEncoding().encode(pstrSMS);

                byte[] b = s.getBytes(StandardCharsets.US_ASCII);*/

                WriteLog("Ori pstrSMS [unicode]=" + pstrSMS);

                //byte[] textByte = pstrSMS.getBytes("UTF-16BE");
                //WriteLog("HexCode [encoded with UTF-16BE]= " + textByte);
                //pstrSMS = textByte.toString(); //cannot convert byte[] to string

        }
        else {
            objReq.setDataCoding((byte)0);
            objReq.setShortMessage(pstrSMS);
        }
```

Comment: Did you find my answer helpful, or do you need more help ?

Comment: you can use message_payload tlv for handling more than 255 byte sms(if supported by your smsc). OR use old User Data Header( UDH)+fragement of message method

Answer (score 0):

Setting user reference (setUserMessageReference) is not enough. You must set also number of fragments and fragment number. Depending on library methods.
Also, you must split message to 255 chunks on hand.
So if you have message 400 bytes, then you do something like this:

```
   First fragment:
   setReference=25
   numberOfFragments=2
   fragmentNumber=1
   message=first 255 bytes

   Second fragment:
   setReference=25
   numberOfFragments=2
   fragmentNumber=2
   message=rest 145 bytes
```

Also note, that many SMSC vendors allow SMPP to be fragmented internally.
There are 2 parameters in SMPP to deal with message:

```
1)Message(mandatory) (limited to 255 bytes)
2)Payload message(optional) (not limited)
```